Expansion of sub rows don't work after filter
Has anyone had a problem with the fact that after applying filters (select) where we choose a row - the subrow disappears and the row is no longer expanded?
I use customFilterFunction ,
     {
        id: 'name',
        accessorFn: (row) => row.name,
        header: ({ column }) => (
          <DataTableColumnHeader column={column} />
        ),
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className="flex" style={{ paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 1.5}rem` }}>
            {row.getCanExpand() && (
              <button onClick={row.getToggleExpandedHandler()} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                {row.getIsExpanded() ? <ArrowDownIcon /> : <ArrowRightIcon />}
              </button>
            )}
            <span>{row.original.name}</span>
          </div>
        ),
        filterFn: customNameFilter,

      },

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: data,
    columns,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    getFacetedUniqueValues: getFacetedUniqueValues(),
    getFacetedRowModel: getFacetedRowModel(),
    getFacetedMinMaxValues: getFacetedMinMaxValues(),
    getSubRows: (row) => row.subItems,
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    onExpandedChange: setExpanded,

    filterFns: {
      fuzzy: customNameFilter,
      select: selectFilter,
    },
    globalFilterFn: customNameFilter,
    state: {
      pagination,
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      expanded,
    },
  });

I want subRows not to disappear after applying a filter to the main row
